# Custom position of PFQueryTableView Loading Spinner

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

I am building an app in Xcode using Parse and programming in Swift.

I have a PFQueryTableViewController. When it loads, it displays the loading spinner and text.

**Is there any way to move the loading spinner so that it is a bit lower down the screen?**

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to move but if you do

"self.loadingViewEnabled = NO;"

in initWithCoder,

you can remove it.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: We can access it only loadingViewEnabled  = YES or NO. it will not appear if you write this code in initWithCoder.